# When to use SDO (Service Data Object) in SOA

Tags: java, soa, sdo

I joined a new team that intensively use SDOs. The concept is new to me but I understand that it is used for unified view of data.  I'm used to accessing the Java persistence entities on the service via DAO's and I find the additional SDO layer a bit heavy. Can you give real life scenario where you successfully used SDOs? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink SDO**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/sdo.php) lead and a member of the [**SDO (JSR-235)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=235) expert group.

An SDO `DataObject` is definitely heavier than a corresponding POJO.  Some advantages of SDOs are the following:

1. Model can be entirely dynamic, no need for a static model.  The generation of static interfaces are optional.
2. There is a very rich metamodel wrt `Type` and `Property` vs regular reflection in Java.
3. When `ChangeSummary` is used you have a built in mechanism for tracking changes.
4. Data can be queried by path not just property name.

Comment: We don't use SDO but we reinvented those last two things ourselves and it involved considerable time, effort, and defects.

Comment: I do some nodeJs + mongodb when I have free time, is the concept of SDO similar to having a model in javascript (since the output of mongodb is JSON your model is dynamic)